# GoogleOpenIDService does not exist in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem to install the library EAuth for yii2. I add the next line in my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "nodge/yii2-eauth": "~2.0"
}
```

After I apply:

```
Coposer update
```

But this no include me the file GoogleOpenIDService
And this show me the next error:
**Class nodge\eauth\services\GoogleOpenIDService does not exist**

Since months I did this same process and it is works, but now not. 
You will have changed something?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Composer documentation [1], the ~ operator selects "the next significant release" from the number you've specified.

Looking at the yii2-eauth repo, the next significant release from `2.0` is `2.4.1` which removes this.

Instead, change your entry in `composer.json` to "~2.0.0" and run `composer update` - this will make sure the version you use is fixed at `2.0.3` which has the file you want in the place it exists.

[1] https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators

Comment: Now, I have the next error Class 'nodge\eauth\openid\ControllerBehavior' not found